# Getting the proxyaddresses attribute of users

Tags: powershell

I have the following line of powershell code i was working on extracting user proxy addresses values. I need all smtp and/or SMTP values like below.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties proxyaddresses | Select-Object Name, @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { $_.ProxyAddresses -join ";"}} | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\proxyaddresses.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

My output :

```
"Name","ProxyAddresses"
"John T","sip:john@contoso.com;smtp:john@contoso1.com;SMTP:john@contoso.com;smtp:john@contoso1.com;X400:C=US;A= ;P=ORG;O=Exchange;S=T;G=John;"
```

My Desired output :

```
"Name","ProxyAddresses"
"John T","smtp:john@contoso1.com;SMTP:john@contoso.com;smtp:john@contoso1.com"
```

Comment: You could try `($_.proxyaddresses -match '^smtp:') -join ';'` in your calculated property

Comment: thanks man I have tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `ProxyAddresses` property will be interpreted as a collection of strings, you can use a [Comparison Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6). The easiest options here are `-like` and `-match`.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties proxyaddresses |
    Select-Object Name, @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -match '^smtp:') -join ";"}}
# Or
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties proxyaddresses |
    Select-Object Name, @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -like 'smtp:*') -join ";"}}
```

`-like` and `-match` are case-insensitive. You can append a `c` to the operator name for the case-sensitive versions. This could be useful when looking for the primary smtp address that begins with `SMTP:`. In that case, you can use:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties proxyaddresses |
    Select-Object Name, @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -cmatch '^SMTP:') -join ";"}}
# OR

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties proxyaddresses |
    Select-Object Name, @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -clike 'SMTP:*') -join ";"}}
```