# Wanting stmp old and new email address from proxyAddresses AD attribute

Tags: powershell, email, active-directory, powershell-4.0

The following script works, but if I put an old email address that a user had it doesn't provide data. I want to show all the new and current emails address with me providing an old email address.

Here is my GitHub where to script is located.

https://github.com/On3n3xus/PowerShell/blob/main/ProxyAddresses

I'm trying to get all the ProxyAddresses data, if I only have an old email address.

Example:

```
$user = Get-ADUser -Filter { EmailAddress -eq "example@gmail.com" } -Properties proxyAddresses
$user.proxyAddresses
```

Comment: You forgot to post the script

Comment: avoid using a scriptblock in the `-Filter` parameter use a string instead. its unclear what your question is about, are you trying to apply that filter querying for `proxyAddresses` 
attribute instead ?

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean? Yes, I'm trying to locate all the data from proxyAddresses and providing a previous email address that a user had and should be in the proxyAddresses data.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Getting the proxyaddresses attribute of users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59469610/getting-the-proxyaddresses-attribute-of-users)

You need to search the `proxyAddresses` attribute.

```
$User = Get-ADUser -Filter { proxyAddresses -like "*${EmailAddress}*" } -Properties proxyAddresses, SamAccountName
```

Comment: I switched this and still no data in the csv while trying to use the previous email address. Reminder the script works with trying a the current email address, but not the previous email address in the txt file.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add SMTP in the email address loop.

```
$User = Get-ADUser -Filter "proxyAddresses -like 'SMTP:*$($EmailAddress)*'" -Properties proxyAddresses, SamAccountName
```

It worked.